# How can I send a request to all my appengine instances

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, google-bigquery

I receive a high, but variable volume of HTTP telemetry requests across instances and Servlet threads.  I want to insertAll to BigQuery in blocks of 500 records to minimise requests, so I cache the data from the requests in concurrent queues, and send the data when the queue reaches 500.  I also use PushQueues to do the writing to BigQuery so the client request doesn't bear the time of this.

I have used ArrayBlockingQueue with success with one exception: I can't find a way to flush my queues.  The scenario is that request traffic stops.  I setup a cron.xml to deliver a flush message every 10 minutes or so to get those last messages out, but of course the cron request is only handled by one instance, so if I have 10 instances, I potentially could have 9 x 499 records jammed up.  I really need a way to get this message to all instances.

I also tried using MemCache, but the mutex flagging required to share queues means this won't scale.

I've also tried Datastore, but that's a bit daft.  Very slow, very costly.

I've chosen appengine so it'll autoscale during varying loads saving costs and administration, but I really can't see a way of solving this.

Comment: If you know an instance's ID you can contact it at https://instance-dot-version-dot-module-dot-app-id.appspot.com if you're an admin for that app.  (If you're not explicitly using modules, the `module` would be named `default`).  Unfortunately I'm not aware of a general API to list the current instances; I believe (not 100% sure) that with manual scaling they'd be 1, 2, ... on up, but that's not documented, so, could change.  I'd recommend opening a feature request for an API or `gcloud preview app` command to list currently alive (instance, version, module) triples.

Comment: Without knowing how you're trying to use it, in what way are you finding Datastore slow?  Are you not able to just push your data onto a Pull Queue and export it to BQ from there with one or more cron jobs? You may find [this article/video](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/332908798) relevant.

Comment: @Alex Thanks.  I thought that might be workable using MemCache and init to register each instance, but unfortunately, that addressing scheme isn't avilable using automatic scaling, only [manual and basic](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Instance_scaling_and_class)

Comment: @tx802 Pull queues didn't appeal to me because they don't autoscale, however they bear further examination.  I was misusing Datastore as a holding cache. Thanks for the great video.

Comment: @tx802 Pull queues are working well.  Thanks for the pointer.  If you want, put it as an answer and I'll mark as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just push your data onto a Pull Queue and export it to BigQuery from there with a cron job.  As a slight variation, you could use cron to enqueue, say, 4 Push Queue tasks 15s apart, for finer control. You may find [this article/video](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/332908798) relevant.

Pull queues are working very well for us in aggregating high volume updates, although if you're adding Tasks to the queue at a 'very' high rate, you may want to shard your queues. [This article](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/fast-and-reliable-ranking-in-datastore/) explains why.  We currently do this, to good effect.

Comment: do you know the name of the article you were referencing? looks like that URL is dead now, but with title i'm sure it can be found.

Comment: If I google the URL, I get a page with [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JuaBy3e6fd4) which I think was probably the one!